# How to change colors of the tracking points and connector lines on the output video using Mediapipe Pose?

Tags: python, mediapipe, video-tracking

I am referring to 33 body points and connector lines between them. I'd like to change the colors of those, especially of the white default color of the connector lines.

Here's my code, I have created a class module for mediapipe which I can import and use in my other programs

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

class poseDetector():

    def __init__(self, mode=False, complex=1, smooth_landmarks=True, segmentation=True, smooth_segmentation=True,
                 detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):

        self.mode = mode
        self.complex = complex
        self.smooth_landmarks = smooth_landmarks
        self.segmentation = segmentation
        self.smooth_segmentation = smooth_segmentation
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mpDrawStyle = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.complex, self.smooth_landmarks, self.segmentation,
                                     self.smooth_segmentation, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)

    def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)
        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, self.results.pose_landmarks,
                                           self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("..//assets//videos//v4.mp4")
    detector = poseDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findPose(img)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: kindly give some code

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I have updated the original post with my minimal working code. Please check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as per the documentation, this is the code for `draw_landmarks`

```
mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
image: numpy.ndarray,
landmark_list: mediapipe.framework.formats.landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList,
connections: Optional[List[Tuple[int, int]]] = None,
landmark_drawing_spec: mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils.DrawingSpec = DrawingSpec(color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2, circle_radius=2),
connection_drawing_spec: mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils.DrawingSpec = DrawingSpec(color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, circle_radius=2),
)
```

So in your `findPose` function you need to update only one line of code

```
def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)
    if self.results.pose_landmarks:
        if draw:
            self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, self.results.pose_landmarks,
                                       self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
            self.mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2),
            self.mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))
    return img
```

The first `self.mpDraw.DrawingSpec` argument corresponds to the points of the landmark. The second `self.mpDraw.DrawingSpec` argument corresponds to the COnnection between those landmarks points.
The `color` is in `(B, G, R)` format

Comment: Hi @Aslan - can you provide a  link to the Mediapipe documentation you referenced?

Comment: @Ghulam you can just hold ctrl and click on draw_landmarks to open the pycharm documentation.

Comment: Hi @ShauryaGoyal - when I `CTRL+click` on the `draw_landmarks` it simply takes me to a earlier section of code where I have defined `draw_landmarks` (rather then any documentation). I am using VSCode 1.75.1. Infact, using `CTRL+click` seems to be designed to highlight (take you to) all occurrences of a variable throughout your code (and not to any associated documentation). Thoughts?

Comment: You can try opening search everywhere(By pressing the shift key twice), and then searching drawing_utils.py, there you can find draw_landmarks.